# iterate array and check value. If the value is between certain value, assign that value as 'x' in a new array

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to iterate through an sorted array and check each value. If the value is between certain range such as `a ~ a*2`, assign a certain value into a new array.

For example, let's say there is `a = 2` and `array_a = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]`. If `array_a[i]` is between `1 ~ a`, assign `1` into a new array `array_b[0] = 1`.

When the number of iteration becomes higher then a, I want to update the compare range to `a ~ a*2`. Which is, check the value of `array_a[3]` if it's between in `a*2 ~ a*3`. Then, when the number of iteration becomes higher than `a*2`, update the compare range to `a*3 ~ a*4` and keep the procedure going on until it iterates through the size of `array_a`.

With the values of `array_a`, the result of `array_b` should be `[1,1,2,2,3,3,4,4,5,5]`.

Comment: It may be a lot easier to think of your problem in terms of division (and rounding) rather than comparing to an interval. Try `[math.ceil(x / a) for x in list_a]`, perhaps? Your example input and output are a little confusing though, as you have 10 input values and only 9 outputs.

Comment: @Blckknght Thanks for the correction about the 9 outputs. The code also seems to work as what I was looking for. I'm not familiar with math functions but I will check out for details and it feels like powerful.

Answer (score 1):

There you go

```
a = 2
array_a = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
array_b = []
for n in array_a:
  j = 1
  while not(a*(j-1) <= n <= a*j):
    j += 1
  array_b.append(j)
print(array_b)
```

Results on

```
[1,1,2,2,3,3,4,4,5,5]
```